# Best way for developing on a remote machine from linux

Tags: python, linux, windows

Working on a python project. I got a virtual windows machine set up for me. My project utilizes tkinter and some external libs. I have a remote desktop access for the remote windows machine.

I there a way to develop code in a linux IDE(possibly eclipse) and save/run it on the remote server with one click and see its outputs.

Simply copying the code to remote machine is not very efficient.

Thanks

Comment: You could look into developing *on* the server via VNC, use rsync over ssh to auto-copy changes, or maybe set up a webdav share and save your code there. It's quite possible, however, that you're asking the wrong question. Rather than further refine a "develop here, test there" pattern, it could be beneficial to identify what factors lead you to believe you need to develop this way. Is it truly the case that you can't create a development environment that accurately represents your production environment? You might go a lot faster if you can address that.

Answer (score 1):

I had done similar things and I think that following might be quite useful for you. You can use eclipse IDE for your development with following plugins :

- PyDev for python
- RSE (Remote System Explorer) for accessing remote machine within eclipse
- RDT (Remote development tool) for development/compilation etc. on remote machine